# django tutorials - add polls on the site

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I just finished the django tutorials 1-6.

I would like to make it so that one can add a poll in the index.html. I find it quite unhandy to have to do it in the admin, and I don't get why they did not add this to the tutorials. It would have been a great feature to learn about.

I have managed to get a text field up, from an  tag, and when press enter the site goes blank and I have to reload to get back to the polls. And of course no new polls have been added..

Here is what I have tried so far:

index.html:

```
<form action='' method='post'> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.add_poll }}
    <input class='btn btn-default' type='text'>
</form>
```

views.py - the indexview, which I added some to

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_poll_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Return the last five published polls (not including those set to be
        published in the future).
        """
        return Poll.objects.filter(
            pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
        ).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

        add_poll = ComposePoll(request.POST or None)
        if add_poll.is_valid():
            create_poll = Poll.save(commit=False)
            create_poll.sent = datetime.datetime.now()
            create_poll.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/polls/')

        poll = Poll.objects.filter()

        return render_to_response('polls/index.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

forms.py - I added the forms.py. it is not in the tutorials. I reused some from the admin.py

```
class ComposePoll(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['question']}),
        ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}), 
        ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that in `get_queryset()`. The only thing to return from there is a queryset, as the name implies, not a redirect. You should probably override `get()`.

Comment: How would I override it? sorry I am pretty new at this still. I tried to change something, move it around a little bit, but it keeps saying that 'return HttpResponseRedirect('/polls/')' is: syntaxerror: 'return' outside function?

Comment: In the same way you defined `get_queryset`, you should define `get`, and move the code there.